# Using Webview2 with PowerShell

Tags: powershell, winforms, webview

I'm working with a PowerShell script that displays a WebView2 window in a Windows Forms GUI. However, I'm having trouble running Javascript code within the WebView2 window. When I try using the "ExecuteScriptAsync" method, it locks up the main form GUI and crashes it immediately. On the other hand, if I use VisualBasic code, it does output the source code of the page, but this approach seems like a really dirty hack.

So, my questions are:

How can I retrieve the source code of the page in PowerShell using WebView2?

1. How can I execute a script within the WebView2 window without using this dirty workaround?
2. Make sure to run PowerShell ISE or console in 32-bit mode as I am using 32-bit DLLs.

```
$teamsdllpath="C:\Users\Administrateur\AppData\Local\Microsoft\TeamsMeetingAddin\1.0.23061.1"

# Get DLLs
$WinForms = "$teamsdllpath\x86\Microsoft.Web.WebView2.WinForms.dll"
$Core = "$teamsdllpath\x86\Microsoft.Web.WebView2.Core.dll"

# Declare objects
Add-Type -Path $WinForms
Add-Type -Language VisualBasic -ReferencedAssemblies PresentationFramework,PresentationCore,WindowsBase,System.Windows.Forms,$WinForms,$Core -TypeDefinition '
    Public Class WebView2ExtendFunctions
        Public Shared Async Sub ExecuteScript(WebView2 As Microsoft.Web.WebView2.WinForms.WebView2, JavaScript As String, Action As System.Action(Of String))
        Dim Value As String = Await WebView2.ExecuteScriptAsync(JavaScript)
        Action(Value)
    End Sub
    End Class
'

# Create forms
$Form = New-Object -TypeName System.Windows.Forms.Form -Property @{Width=900;Height=800}
$WebView2 = New-Object -TypeName Microsoft.Web.WebView2.WinForms.WebView2
$WebView2.CreationProperties = New-Object -TypeName 'Microsoft.Web.WebView2.WinForms.CoreWebView2CreationProperties'
$WebView2.CreationProperties.UserDataFolder = "c:\temp\webviewuserdata"
$WebView2.Source = "https://www.example.com"
$WebView2.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(884, 760)

# Action on navigation complete
$WebView2_NavigationCompleted = {
    [WebView2ExtendFunctions]::ExecuteScript($WebView2, "document.documentElement.outerHTML", [Action[String]]{param ($global:html) Write-Host $html})
    Start-Sleep 3
    $form.Close()
}
$WebView2.add_NavigationCompleted($WebView2_NavigationCompleted)

# Show the form
$form.Controls.Add($WebView2)
$form.Add_Shown({$form.Activate()})
$form.ShowDialog()
```

I tried to create a Job in Powershell with Start-Job, but oviously failed because can't pass objects to the job

Answer (score 0):

I have confirmed that it works by using the following code. Particularly important changes are embedded in comments with "! embedded in the comment.

```
$teamsdllpath=$PSScriptRoot  # memp: set dlls to script's dir

# Get DLLs
$WinForms = "$teamsdllpath\Microsoft.Web.WebView2.WinForms.dll"
$Core     = "$teamsdllpath\Microsoft.Web.WebView2.Core.dll"

# Declare objects
Add-Type -Path $WinForms

# Create forms
$Form     = New-Object -TypeName System.Windows.Forms.Form -Property @{Width=900;Height=800}
$WebView2 = New-Object -TypeName Microsoft.Web.WebView2.WinForms.WebView2
$WebView2.CreationProperties = New-Object -TypeName 'Microsoft.Web.WebView2.WinForms.CoreWebView2CreationProperties'
$WebView2.CreationProperties.UserDataFolder = $PSScriptRoot  # memo: change workdir to script's dir
$WebView2.Source = "https://www.example.com"
$WebView2.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(884, 760)

# Action on navigation complete
$WebView2_NavigationCompleted = {
    $WebView2.ExecuteScriptAsync("window.chrome.webview.postMessage(document.documentElement.outerHTML);");  # !memo: replace this line to ExecuteScriptAsync!
    Start-Sleep 3
    $form.Close()
}
$WebView2.add_NavigationCompleted($WebView2_NavigationCompleted)

# !memo: add this block to receive from webview2's message !
$WebView2.add_WebMessageReceived({
    param($WebView2, $message)
    Write-Host $message.TryGetWebMessageAsString()
})

# Show the form
$form.Controls.Add($WebView2)
$form.Add_Shown({$form.Activate()})
$form.ShowDialog()
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for your script. It is working fine with few tweeks on my platform.